# Get data to page from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I'm trying to get data from a C# WinForm to a page, but I'm stuck at the point of receiving data. How do i know that C# app is sending data to the page?

How do i get data using JavaScript?

The important thing is that the page is not on my computer, it is on the Appframe framework, where you can create web applications using HTML and JS.
I am not using PHP

I have this code for sending data as HTTP query:

```
string cardData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(apduResponse, 0, responseLength - 2);

string url = "https://training-test.appframe.com/sedusov-bd-user-login";
string data = "cardData=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(cardData);
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    textBox1.Text = "data was sent!";
}
```

Also i have this code for getting data

```
fetch("https://training-test.appframe.com/sedusov-bd-user-login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  },
  body: "cardData=" + encodeURIComponent(cardData)
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Received data:", data);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error when sending the request:", error);
  });
```

Maybe I do not understand how to receive, or send the data incorrectly, but in the console I get this error and do not understand what it has to do

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything about the js code but in the C# code where you do:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

the 'response' variable will be of type **HttpResponseMessage** ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=net-7.0)) and thus for the sake of ensuring the success status code you can use `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and catch the exception thrown if the status is different than success, or you can do an if statement like so:

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
//handle status codes different than success.
}
```